# How to draw a sphere in D3D11, given position and radius?

Tags: c++, graphics, direct3d, direct3d11

To draw a sphere, one does not need to know anything else but it's position and radius. Thus, rendering a sphere by passing a triangle mesh sounds very inefficient unless you need per-vertex colors or other such features. Despite googling, searching [D3D11 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/atoc-dx-graphics-direct3d-11) and reading [Introduction to 3D Programming with DirectX 11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936420228), I failed to understand

1. Is it possible to draw a sphere by passing only the position and radius of it to the GPU?
2. If not, what is the main principle I have misunderstood?
3. If yes, how to do it?

My ultimate goal is to pass more parameters later on which will be used by a shader effect.

Comment: In the 1980s when writing games in Z80 machine code, you could draw circles without taking the square root or using any trigonometric functions. The latter are still expensive on modern computers. I wonder if the now 40 year old optimisations persist?

Comment: I think you're underestimating just how fast GPUs are at drawing triangles. They don't waste hardware on being able to draw primitive shapes like spheres because there's no need.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement [Geometry Shader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/geometry-shader-stage). This shader should take Sphere center and radius as input and emit a banch of vertices for rasterization. In general this is called point sprites.

Comment: Maybe not for vertex shader because it's before geometry shader in the rendering pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use tessellation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_(computer_graphics)

Most of the mess will be generated on the gpu side.

Note:
In the end you still have more parameters sent to the shaders because the sphere will be split into triangles that will be each rendered individually on the screen.
But the split is done on the gpu side.

Comment: Are you sure there is no such thing as passing just one vertex and drawing a sphere from that? Like one huge particle.

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* create a sphere from a point & vertex on the GPU, it's generally not very efficient. With higher-end GPUs you could use Hardware Tessellation, but even that would be better done a different way.

The better solution is to use instancing and render lots of the same VB/IB of sphere geometry scaled to different positions and sizes.